# Emulate call in Android Emulator with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

How can I interact with an Android emulator attached to IntelliJ IDEA?

And be able to do the following:

- Make fake call
- Send fake SMS
- Browse a filesystem
- Make profiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interact with android emulator  the same way you did it in eclipse. It can be found in directory you placed android sdk, in my case (android-sdk-windows). Then go to directory

> tools

and run

```
ddms batch file (ddms.bat)
```

Everything else similar the way you did in eclipse. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I can't connect IDEA's debugger & ddms to the single Android instance simultaneously.